# Nodejs database fails for both mongoose and cloud mongodb with "No valid exports main found for `...\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In a barebones node.js app I am unable to connect to either a local mongoose database or a cloud mongoDB database.

Here is the error:

```
Error: No valid exports main found for 'D:\Documents\code\node-api\node_modules\mongodb-connec
tion-string-url'
←[90m    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:9)←[39m
←[90m    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:502:14)←[39m
←[90m    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:22)←[3
9m
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:855:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Documents\code\node-api\node_modules\←[4mmongodb←[24m\lib\connec
tion_string.js:6:41)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here are 2 code snippets that both yield the error:
local:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = async () => {
    try{
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true});
        console.log("Database connected");
    }catch(error)
    {
        console.log("error: ", error);
        throw new Error(error);
    }
   
}
```

and cloud:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://user1:<[mypasswordgoeshere]>@cluster0.vl2la.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

There are many questions here with a similar error, and I've followed the steps for as many as possible, including reinstalling the packages, delete node_modules and reinstalling, installing autoprefixer, and downgrading versions of various packages. It's important to note that I'm on Windows 7 and therefore cannot update my node.js version any further.

Here is my packages.json file:

```
{
  "name": "node-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: I'm using node.js version 13.6.0, which I think is the latest version compatible with Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, starting the server in Node.js terminal produces this error. Doing everything from Windows 7 cmd works perfectly without this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `mongo-connection-string-url` package. Was running node 13.3.0, upgrading to 14.17.5 resolved the issue.